# how to Typecast File object into InputStream

Tags: java

How to Typecast File object into InputStream.

```
File file=new File("c:\\abc.txt");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
        File file=new File("c:\\abc.txt");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
```

or

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("c:\\abc.txt");
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't typecast the file to Input stream, you create an InputStream object using the file as parameter. You can use [FileInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html):

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Comment: Yes, it's fine too. But wherever you use `InputStream`, you may use `FileInputStream`

Answer (score 1):

Use `file` as a parameter in a [`FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.io.File%29) Object.

Like this,

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

> Creates a FileInputStream by opening a connection to an actual file,
>   the file named by the File object file in the file system. A new
>   FileDescriptor object is created to represent this file connection.